# Ansible module for running commands inside vcenter server or Running certificate manager

Tags: ansible, ssl-certificate, vmware, ca, vcenter

I want to automate the process of "Replacing the certificate" using certificate-manager of vcenter through ansible playbook for vcenter. I have all 3 required certificates (I have generated it from third part CA) which we need to pass inside certificate-manager and manually it is working as expected.
I have written ansible-playbook which will generate all these certificates and by copying these certificates in vcenter and applying it in certificate manager manually , it is working as expected.

I want to automate the above process using ansible module from outside. I have vcenter's all required data (IP address, credentials etc) and want to run it from my local linux machine which will run and do the same job as certificate manager is doing.

For this I have 2 approaches in my mind. (There may be any other better approach as well)

1. Find any ansible module which will help me to run commands inside vcenter's server and I'll run certificate-manager along with expect(pexpect) module and follow the steps which I have followed manually while running certificate manager
2. I need to write/use ansible module which will do the complete same job for me rather then executing all commands one by one.

Comment: Approach 1. will work as expected.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for suggestions. Can you provide the command for the same?

Comment: That is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did it using VMARE's API REST, not running the commands inside the VCENTER

```
   - name: Get authentication cookie
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ vcenter_hostname }}/rest/com/vmware/cis/session"
    method: POST
    user: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 200,404
    timeout: 10
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: session_cookie

- name: Upload Trusted CA
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ vcenter_hostname }}/rest/vcenter/certificate-management/vcenter/trusted-root-chains/"
    method: POST
    validate_certs: no
    return_content: yes
    status_code: 200
    timeout: 10
    headers:
      vmware-api-session-id: "{{ session_cookie.cookies['vmware-api-session-id'] }}"
      Content-Type: application/json
    body_format: json
    body: {"spec":{"cert_chain":{"cert_chain":["{{ lookup('file', '/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root-ca.crt')| trim }}"]}}}
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: upload_trusted_ca_output
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Upload VCENTER's KEY and CRT
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ vcenter_hostname }}/rest/vcenter/certificate-management/vcenter/tls"
    method: PUT
    validate_certs: no
    return_content: yes
    status_code: 200
    timeout: 10
    headers:
      vmware-api-session-id: "{{ session_cookie.cookies['vmware-api-session-id'] }}"
      Content-Type: application/json
    body_format: json
    body: {"spec":{"cert":"{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].vars.vcenter_hostname }}.crt')| trim }}","key":"{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].vars.vcenter_hostname }}-noRSA.key')| trim }}"}}
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Then you have to wait around 10 minutes to ensure certificates are applied and finally reboot the VCENTER

API REST endpoints can be checked and tested in your VCENTER

https://**VCENTER_IP**/ui/#?extensionId=com.vmware.vsphere.client.h5.devcenter.apiexplorer&forceNavigate